# Problem accesing my zend framework app through lan connection to my ubuntu server hosting

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, apache-2.2

What I Want to do:  access my zend framework app from other computer in my private lan

e.g: `//192.168.x.x/my_app`

- 192.168.x.x is my ubuntu server ip (from ifconfig)
- my_app is  a virtualhost that I set in the server (/etc/hosts and apache2).

In my server if I do `//my_app` it works.

In another pc if I do `//192.168.x.x` it shows "It's working" default message but
if I do `//192.168.x.x/my_app` it "Not found on this server"

Server settings

`/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.1.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 my_app
```

`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www"
        ServerName localhost:80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my_app
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_app/public"

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory "/var/www/my_app/public">
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your ServerName and your IP to another pc's /etc/hosts file.
Of course you should have ServerName in your virtualhost file.

Comment: I did that in system32/drivers/etc/host 
192.168.x.x    my_app
but isn't that for using my_app instead of the ip in the browser of my "guest" machine (windows 7 in this case)?
Sorry if I'm saying something stupid networks is not strong in my knowledge base :(. Thanks for replying :)

Comment: Ok..i'm sooo stupid. Can't tell why but I try again and IT WORKS!! 
Thanks again, I read that "host thing" in every post over the internet but yours really touch me :P. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "_" in server name